# Firefox Extensions: Set Order of Execution

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

tl;dr: Is there any way to set the order of execution of Firefox Extensions?

Currently I'm using uBlock to block a request whose URI contains elements of tracking (like `domain.com/?utm_source=facebook`). I developed a Firefox extension that cuts those parts out (simple RegEx). Unfortunately my extension gets executed *after* uBlock: When a request contains `utm_source`, uBlock stops the further loading of a page. If my extension executes first, I would get rid of some tracking and uBlock wouldn't stop the page to load.

Is there any way to assign a "higher priority" to my extension?

Comment: You might be interested in https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/neat-url/

Comment: Yeah, that's a step in the right direction (nice work btw) - have you tried to operate Firefox with other extensions (like uBlock), too? Any experiences with the behavior?

Comment: There are a few issues with multiple addons rewriting the same requests. I always tried to avoid it. However, I didn't encounter issues yet with Neat URL and uBlock installed in the same profile. If you encounter a bug, feel free to submit it to bugzilla: http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/